# Spring Security UserDetails cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to cache UserDetails in Spring security for our Rest API. There are plenty examples about using EhCacheBasedUserCache but few for SpringCacheBasedUserCache. SpringCacheBasedUserCache seems something is new( after 3.1 Spring Security?). What is the difference between SpringCacheBasedUserCache  and EhCacheBasedUserCache? When should we choose one over the other? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[EhCacheBasedUserCache](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/cache/EhCacheBasedUserCache.html) uses, as the name implies, the widely used [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) library for actual caching.

[SpringCacheBasedUserCache](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/cache/SpringCacheBasedUserCache.html) uses Spring's own caching abstraction. With this you can for example plugin JCache, a.k.a. JSR-107. The reason you find fewer examples of this is that it is newer, the [JSR-107 did not reach a Final Release until 18 Mar, 2014](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107). Note that JSR-107 is an API, not an actual implementation.

How to choose? Ehcache is mature and well-tested. JCache probably has a good future thanks to the JSR standards process.